# accepts_nested_attributes_for for STI Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, thinking-sphinx, sti

Here is my current model structure

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = 'customer_type'

  has_one :contact
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact
end

class Vendor < Customer

  has_many :domains
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :domains
end

class Club < Customer
end
```

When i create a form for vendor

```
= form_for @vendor do |f|
  = f.fields_for :contact do |c|
    ....
  = f.fields_for :domains do |d|
    ...
```

it renders properly. Same thing with club without the domains. Now when i edit it and click update for vendor for it gives me the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:327:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_one_to_one_association'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:288:in `contact_attributes='
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:in `block in assign_attributes'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `each'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `assign_attributes'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:212:in `block in update_attributes'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:190:in `transaction'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb:34:in `update'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in _run__551367052__process_action__739945711__callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_1211'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:326:in `around'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:310:in `_callback_around_13'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_1211'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__551367052__process_action__739945711__callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/journey-1.0.0/lib/journey/router.rb:60:in `block in call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/journey-1.0.0/lib/journey/router.rb:48:in `each'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/journey-1.0.0/lib/journey/router.rb:48:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:570:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/sass-3.1.12/lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/warden-1.1.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__575954635__call__637953697__callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:102:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:14:in `block in call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:14:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:132:in `forward'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:139:in `pass'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:151:in `invalidate'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:70:in `call!'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/rack-cache-1.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:50:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:206:in `start_request_handler'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:171:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:166:in `handle_spawn_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
:
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
[GEM_ROOT]/gems/passenger-3.0.11/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `&lt;main&gt;'
```

If I take `domains` association and move that into customer, it works fine.. but it does seem to like having that association in the child model.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a peculiar bug?

**Update:** We recently installed thinking sphinx into the application. It could be related to that as well.

Comment: Did you run a migration to add a "type" column to your Customer table?

Comment: our `inheritance_column` is customer_type. yes the migrations have run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the fix. the problem was that we added the `define_index` block after the association definition but before the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` definition. we moved it below everything and everything works fine now.